# How to get values of radio button if they are disabled using Jquery in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

In Application, i have group of question and answer. Every question has 3 set of answer that type are radio button.all question and answer in form. if i answer any question and click on next button then that question's answer will disabled. 
Right now i disabled it on next but at the last when i click on submit.then i am getting all values from `form` submit.

Script Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.forward').click(function(event) {
       $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(index, el) {
           var title = $(this).attr('name');
            $("input[name="+title+"]:radio").attr('disabled',true);

       });
    });
</script>
```

In Codeigniter Code :

```
function insertValues() {
     $answer = $this->input->post();
}
```

Html Code:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/demo/insertValues">

<div>
<h3>Question 1 ?</h3>
<input name="1" type="radio" value="111">
<input name="1" type="radio" value="112">
<input name="1" type="radio" value="113">
</div>

<div>
<h3>Question 2 ?</h3>
<input name="2" type="radio" value="121">
<input name="2" type="radio" value="122">
<input name="2" type="radio" value="123">
</div>

<button type="button" name="forward" class="forward">Save &amp; Next</button>


<button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">See Report</button>
</form>
```

Comment: so  what you want? what your problem now?

Comment: when i submit for i could not get all radio button values when the are disabled. without disabled i am able to get it. So how to do this ?

Comment: Use `readonly` attribute instead of disabling. Then you can receive all field value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to enable them in a submit event handler

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(){
        $(this).find(':radio').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('form input[type=radio]').each(function(){
      if($(this).prop('disabled',true) == true)
           alert('My property is disabled'+$(this).val());
 }
```

Comment: `if($(this).prop('disabled',true) == true)` ... will never be true. A jQuery setter will return original jQuery object, not boolean

Comment: You wanted getter ... `if($(this).prop('disabled'))`